# R read csv error. passing file name from another value

Tags: r, csv, filenames

I am having an error with passing a value to be used as file name in read.csv command in R

I have a bunch of csv files, each one is assigned to a value Mx_csv where x is a number from 1 to 8 for example.

```
M3_csv <- "123123_out.csv"
M4_csv <- "178787_out.csv"
```

I select which M I want to work on by changing 1 line of code:

```
Ma = "M4" // that then tells all following code which M to use
setwd(paste0("D:/RA_",Ma))  // sets the working directory folder RA_M4 

filenm <- paste0(Ma,"_csv")
Mn <- read.csv(file = filenm,header = TRUE)
```

in this case x becomes "M4_csv", but rather than the read.csv command loading 178787_out.csv it tries to load a file called M4_csv and errors.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but google isn't helping me find an answer

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: You can try `get(paste0(Ma,"_csv"))`. My understanding of the get function is that it searches the environment for a object with that name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to put you filenames into a list. Additionally it's probably not necessary to switch the working directory as you could add the path to your data files to the filename using e.g. `file.path`:

```r
fn_list <- list(
  M3 = "123123_out.csv",
  M4 = "178787_out.csv"
)

Ma <- "M4"
filenm <- file.path(paste0("D:/RA_",Ma), fn_list[[Ma]])
filenm
#> [1] "D:/RA_M4/178787_out.csv"

Mn <- read.csv(file = filenm, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.
I'm trying to run an IF on that now,
if (Ma = M1) {Mn_dt <- 5} else if (Ma = M2) {
 Mn_dt <- 10} etc..
but getting unexpected '=' in "if (Manta ="
tried using "M1" but same thing.